# Vuetify data table: add insert row icon

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm looking for a way to add a dynamic "Insert Row" icon to a Vuetify data-table, similar to the screenshot below:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Use template to insert a div that reveals only on hover with a sidebutton on absolute:

```html
<v-data-table>
  <template #item="{ item }">
    <div class="myBorderBottomBlueClass"> // only reveal on hover
      // my icon in absolute position left with @click
    </div>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```